# How to access elements of JSON response

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two types of answers that JSON format is for me since then, and I want to parse this information.

```
response = {'success': True, 'alarms': [{'play_voice': True}, {'voice_url': 'my directory'}]}

response = {'success': True, 'alarms': [{'play_voice': False}]}
```

when I try this code I have this output:

```
voice_prof = [alarm is not None for alarm in response['alarms'] if alarm.get('play_voice', 0) != 0][0]
```

when 'play_voice' is True, then my code works fine but I have a 'play_voice' is False then this code does not run at all.

Comment: The list is empty if there are no dictionaries in the list with True values for play_voice, so asking for the first such dictionary is an IndexError; is that what you mean? Why is that unexpected?

Comment: yes,i get this error:list index out of range

Comment: Again, why is that unexpected? What output should you get in the second case? What does voice_prof mean? Give a [mcve] and some more context.

Comment: i want to get voice_prof ==True or voice_prof == False

Comment: when {'play_voice': True} then i get voice_prof == True,but when  {'play_voice': False} then i have 'list index out of range ' error

Comment: Then your filtering condition is wrong, because `False == 0`. Try `alarm.get(play_voice) is not None` or `"play_voice" in alarm` instead. Also the resulting value in the list comprehension isn't right; it will always be True.

Comment: This does not look like JSON at all. What you have is a Python `dict` (which may well have come from parsing some JSON, but you are not showing us that).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the value of the `play_voice` key for the first dictionary containing such key in the `alarms` list, in which case both sides of your list comprehension are wrong and you want something like:

```
voice_prof = [
    alarm["play_voice"]  # value for that key 
    for alarm in response["alarms"] 
    if "play_voice" in alarm  # if it contains that key
][0]
```

A more efficient implementation would be to only find the first such dictionary, using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), rather than run through the whole `alarms` list:

```
voice_prof = next(
    alarm["play_voice"]  # value for that key 
    for alarm in response["alarms"] 
    if "play_voice" in alarm  # if it contains that key
)
```